# My Plug Says It's USB, I can't Identify

Tags: cameras, usb, identification

I ordered this cool little USB endoscope camera, but the cord does not look like any type of USB I have ever seen. I would eventually like to make this act like a webcam, so does that make a difference? It looks like this:

The back is just flat. I tried plugging in an Arduino RedBot cord because I had one lying around, it doesn't fit.

Comment: Connector in picture is molex picoblade http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction
May be you should post about make and model number of camera which can provide more insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB is more than just a connector.  It is a standard communications protocol, voltage levels, and even wiring colors.

[image]

I suggest you get a standard USB cable, cut it in half, then splice in your wires.  http://wikipedia.org/wiki/USB does a good job of describing the pin outs on the various USB connectors.